# Pip -- no module named 'pip._internal'

Tags: python, pip

I've come across the following bu in using `pip` recently:

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

$ uname -a
Linux 13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 15:46:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea how to fix this, or do I need to completely reinstall pip?

Comment: What does `python -m pip --version` give?

Comment: @PeterWood an error also. I think it may have to do with permissions/sudo ability.